# Run awk file from shell script without specifying awk's exact location

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I'm trying to debug a shell script that calls an awk file.  *Which is a nightmare, cause I've never used either before, nor am I very fluent with linux, but anyway*

A dev made an awk file and is trying to run it in a shell script.

To try and run it from a separate location, without needing to specify the exact location, they put the awk script in a folder that's in the PATH variable. So that awk file should be available everywhere, right?

When you run it like this...

> awk -f script.awk arg1

**...can awk find that script?** It spits out an error, when the shell script tries to run that awk command:

> awk: fatal: can't open source file `script.awk' for reading (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you know, `awk` can't find the script itself.

If the script is marked as executable, and if you have a `which` command, then you should be able to do:

```
awk -f `which script.awk` arg1
```

Alternatively, and probably better, make the script into an executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 
BEGIN { x = 23 }
      { x += 2 }
END   { print x }
```

The shebang needs the '`-f`' option to work on MacOS X 10.7.1 where I tested it:

```
$ script.awk script.awk
31
$
```

That gives you a self-contained single-file solution.

Comment: +1 for the `#!` approach, although many UNIXes should prefer `#!/usr/bin/env awk` ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env))

Comment: @sehe: I'd use `#!/usr/bin/env awk` except you are only guaranteed one argument, and I needed that for the `-f`.  Indeed, I tried with `#!/usr/bin/env awk` and faced some frustration when it did not work (but, on going back, using `#!/usr/bin/env awk -f` did work on MacOS X).  YMMV.  It was worth mentioning `#!/usr/bin/env`...

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not going to work. awk needs the path to the script to run, it won't use the PATH variable to find it. PATH is only used to find executables.

Comment: Exactly, the command should be something like `awk -f /path/to/script.awk arg1`.